# Does $AB$ means $A\times B$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What will $AB$ be when $A=2, B=3$? 
My teacher says 6, But I do not agree.
Because there is no operator between $A$ and $B$.
Now we are arguing.

I know that $AB$ means $A\times B$ in the daily sense. But it loses the rigorousness of mathematics.

So my question is that, in the rigorous mathematical sense, $AB$ is different from $A\times B$, Right? Because in group theory, you always have to specify your binary operator.

Comment: This is just notation.  When  the setting is clear, it is not unusual to write $ab$ for $a\times b$.

Comment: And here I thought that it is $A\cdot B$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notations and symbols  are mostly understood with respect to the context.

If $A=2$ and $B=3$ then $AB$ can stand for $23$ which is not $6$.

So we have to pay attention to the context.

For example when we write $35$ we mean $3\times 10 +5$ and we do not mean $3\times 5$

When we deal with vectors, $A\times B$ means cross product and $A.B$ means dot product which are totally different concepts.

In group theory $AB$ and $BA$ are not necessarily the same element while in number theory they are the same number.

Pay attention to the context and everything starts making sense.